# spring boot bootBuildImage applying war on tomcat image

Tags: spring-boot

With spring boot and task bootBuildImage(gradle), is it possible build an image based on say a tomcat image, and copy the war file into relevant webapp directory, as opposed to running an application fatjar?

I know this is possible with jib.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when using the Paketo buildpacks (the default with Spring Boot's `bootBuildImage` Gradle task), because Paketo includes a [Tomcat buildpack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat).

It does require some configuration of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to get a non-executable war file so that the Paketo Tomcat buildpack will detect the correct application type and configure Tomcat with the war file.

Add the following configuration to the `build.gradle` file to instruct Spring Boot to create a non-executable war file as shown in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-and-normal):

```
war {
    enabled = true
}

bootWar {
    classifier = 'boot'
}
```

Also add the following configuration so the `bootBuildImage` task will use the non-executable war file:

```
bootBuildImage {
    jar = war.archiveFile
}
```

After these changes, running `bootBuildImage` should show that the `apache-tomcat` buildpack is participating in the image generation:

```
 > Running creator
[creator]     ===> DETECTING
[creator]     5 of 18 buildpacks participating
[creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   1.0.1
[creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 5.2.1
[creator]     paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat     3.1.0
[creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          2.2.2
[creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       3.5.0
```

Without the additional configuration you would see the `paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar` buildpack instead of `paketo-buildpacks/apache-tomcat`, indicating that the fat executable jar was used to launch the application instead of a war deployed to Tomcat.